iText 8 ConvertToPDF Memory Leak Issue Net 8
We have a program that creates PDFs based on inputted information. The generated PDFs range form a single page to 1000+ pages. We were previously using Net 6 and iText7.pdfhtml - 4.0.2 with no issues, however upon upgrading to Net 8 and iText7.pdfhtml - 5.0.3 we have noticed a spike in memory usage when a PDF is generated (the greater the PDF size the greater the memory usage). This memory usage spike occurs when
HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, pdfDocument, properties);

is called. The memory used during the creation of the PDF is not disposed of upon completion.
On our IIS server, the memory used is stored in the Generation 2 heap, and it not collected by the garbage collector. Eventually our server will run out of memory and the application pool is restarted.
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(html))

{

    using (var workStream = new MemoryStream())
    
    using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(workStream))
    
    {
    
        var watermark = isDraft ? "DRAFT" : string.Empty;
        
        ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties();
        
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        
        if (landscape)
            
            pdfDocument.SetDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
            
            PdfDocEventHandler handler = new PdfDocEventHandler(formDocument.ConfirmationID, formDocument.SubmittedDate, watermark);
            
            pdfDocument.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, handler);
            
            HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(html, pdfDocument, properties);
            
            pdfOut = AddPageNumbers(workStream.ToArray(), formDocument.ConfirmationID, formDocument.SubmittedDate);
    }
}

Using NetBrains, we were able to identify the main memory usage culprit was coming from iText.Layout.Borders where “set_Capacity” tried to grab 28GB of memory.
NetBrains - set_Capacity size
Throughout the PDF creation process, our Generation 2 heap continues to steadily grow, and garbage collection never decreases the size of the heap.
Generation 2 heap growth
We have been unable to find a resolution in our research. Has anyone experienced a similar issue / knows why this is happening?

just wanted to give a quick heads up, that we are investigating this issue

Great thank you - any progress in identifying the source of this issue?

It would help a lot if you provide an html file to reproduce. Also the code of PdfDocEventHandler would be useful if the issue is not reproducible without.

The research conducted by our team indicates that the issue you're facing isn't unique and is likely related to processing large tables. Additionally, it's evident that there are no regressions between versions, suggesting that the problem probably isn't linked to changes in the library or .NET code.
Also, based on your screenshots, it can be seen that 28GB of memory is allocated for a certain period of time and at the peak the memory is occupied up to ~ 9GB. After the document has been processed, the memory is cleared automatically or you can call GC.Collect();
To better understand the problem and potentially offer a more effective solution, we need to examine the HTML document you're attempting to convert. Please provide this document, and we'll endeavor to analyze it to identify which parts might be causing such significant memory consumption during conversion.

The html document is quite large - what is the best way to provide?

Here are links to the code used to generate the pdf (https://jmp.sh/92xI2tOV) and a sample html document (https://jmp.sh/lSVphlYT)

Thanks! We will have a look and come back with the investigation result.

We increased the size of your file by duplicating tables and used the code you provided for testing. No regressions were found between the versions. After processing the file, the Garbage Collector successfully cleaned up the memory. The information in the response is relevant: the bigger tables you have in the file, the higher the memory consumption.
